# Updating NSView asynchronously from a thread

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, quartz-2d, agent-based-modeling

First of all, I'm an Objective-C novice. So I'm not very familiar with OS X or iOS development. My experience is mostly in Java.

I'm creating an agent-based modeling-framework. I'd like to display the simulations and to do that I'm writing a little application. First, a little bit about the framework. The framework has a `World` class, in which there is a `start` method, which iterates over all agents and has them perform their tasks. At the end of one "step" of the world (i.e., after all the agents have done their thing), the `start` method calls the `intercept` method of an object that implements `InterceptorProtocol`. This object was previously passed in via the constructor. Using the interceptor, anyone can get a hook into the state of the world. This is useful for logging, or in the scenario that I'm trying to accomplish: displaying the information in a graphical manner. The call to `intercept` is synchronous.

Now as far as the GUI app is concerned, it is pretty simple. I have a controller that initializes a custom view. This custom view also implements `InterceptorProtocol` so that it can listen in, to what happens in the world. I create a `World` object and pass in the view as an interceptor. The view maintains a reference to the world through a private property and so once I have initialized the world, I set the view's world property to the world I have just created (I realize that this creates a cycle, but I need a reference to the world in the `drawRect` method of the view and the only way I can have it is if I maintain a reference to it from the class).

Since the world's `start` method is synchronous, I don't start the world up immediately. In the `drawRect` method I check to see if the world is running. If it is not, I start it up in a background thread. If it is, I examine the world and display all the graphics that I need to.

In the `intercept` method (which gets called from `start` running on the background thread), I set `setNeedsToDisplay` to `YES`. Since the `start` method of the world is running in a separate thread, I also have a lock object that I use to synchronize so that I'm not working on the `World` object while it's being mutated (this part is kind of janky and it's probably not working the way I expect it to - there are more than a few rough spots and I'm simply trying to get a little bit working; I plan to clean up later).

My problem is that the view renders some stuff, and then it pretty much locks up. I can see that the `NSLog` statements are being called and so the code is running, but nothing is getting updated on the view.

Here's some of the pertinent code:

**MasterViewController**

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "World.h"
#import "InfectableBug.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _worldView = [[WorldView alloc] init];

        World* world = [[World alloc] initWithName: @"Bhumi"
                                              rows: 100
                                           columns: 100
                                        iterations: 2000
                                  snapshotInterval: 1
                                       interceptor: _worldView];
        for(int i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
            NSMutableString* name = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"HealthyBug"];
            [name appendString: [[NSNumber numberWithInt: i] stringValue]];
            [world addBug: [[InfectableBug alloc] initWithWorld: world
                                                           name: name
                                                          layer: @"FirstLayer"
                                                       infected: NO
                                                infectionRadius: 1
                                               incubationPeriod: 10
                                        infectionStartIteration: 0]];
        }

        NSLog(@"Added all bugs. Going to add infected");

        [world addBug: [[InfectableBug alloc] initWithWorld: world
                                                       name: @"InfectedBug"
                                                      layer: @"FirstLayer"
                                                   infected: YES
                                            infectionRadius: 1
                                           incubationPeriod: 10
                                    infectionStartIteration: 0]];

        [_worldView setWorld: world];

        //[world start];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSView*) view {
    return self.worldView;
}

@end
```

**WorldView**

```
#import "WorldView.h"
#import "World.h"
#import "InfectableBug.h"

@implementation WorldView

@synthesize world;

- (id) initWithFrame:(NSRect) frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) drawRect:(NSRect) dirtyRect {

    CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextClearRect(myContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768));

    NSUInteger rows = [world rows];
    NSUInteger columns = [world columns];

    NSUInteger cellWidth = 1024 / columns;
    NSUInteger cellHeight = 768 / rows;

    if([world running]) {
        @synchronized (_lock) {
            //Ideally we would need layers, but for now let's just get this to display
            NSArray* bugs = [world bugs];
            NSEnumerator* enumerator = [bugs objectEnumerator];
            InfectableBug* bug;
            while ((bug = [enumerator nextObject])) {
                if([bug infected] == YES) {
                    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(myContext, 128, 0, 0, 1);
                } else {
                    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(myContext, 0, 0, 128, 1);
                }

                NSLog(@"Drawing bug %@ at %lu, %lu with width %lu and height %lu", [bug name], [bug x] * cellWidth, [bug y] * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);

                CGContextFillRect(myContext, CGRectMake([bug x] * cellWidth, [bug y] * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight));
            }
        }
    } else {
        [world performSelectorInBackground: @selector(start) withObject: nil];
    }
}

- (BOOL) isFlipped {
    return YES;
}

- (void) intercept: (World *) aWorld {

    struct timespec time;
    time.tv_sec  = 0;
    time.tv_nsec = 500000000L;

    //nanosleep(&time, NULL);

    @synchronized (_lock) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay: YES];
    }
}

@end
```

**start** method in **World.m**:

```
- (void) start {

    running = YES;

    while(currentIteration < iterations) {

        @autoreleasepool {

            [bugs shuffle];

            NSEnumerator* bugEnumerator = [bugs objectEnumerator];
            Bug* bug;

            while((bug = [bugEnumerator nextObject])) {

                NSString* originalLayer = [bug layer];
                NSUInteger originalX = [bug x];
                NSUInteger originalY = [bug y];

                //NSLog(@"Bug %@ is going to act and location %i:%i is %@", [bug name], [bug x], [bug y], [self isOccupied: [bug layer] x: [bug x] y: [bug y]] ? @"occupied" : @"not occupied");
                [bug act];
                //NSLog(@"Bug has acted");

                if(![originalLayer isEqualToString: [bug layer]] || originalX != [bug x] || originalY != [bug y]) {
                    //NSLog(@"Bug has moved");
                    [self moveBugFrom: originalLayer atX: originalX atY: originalY toLayer: [bug layer] atX: [bug x] atY: [bug y]];
                    //NSLog(@"Updated bug position");
                }
            }

            if(currentIteration % snapshotInterval == 0) {
                [interceptor intercept: self];
            }

            currentIteration++;
        }
    }

    //NSLog(@"Done.");
}
```

Please let me know if you'd like to see any other code. I realize that the code is not pretty; I was just trying to get stuff to work and I plan on cleaning it up later. Also, if I'm violating an Objective-C best practices, please let me know!

*Stepping out for a bit; sorry if I don't respond immediately!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew, quiet a question for probably a simple answer:  ;)

**UI updates have to be performed on the main thread**

If I read your code correctly, you call the `start` method on a background thread. The start method contains stuff like `moveBugFrom:...` and also the `intercept:` method. The intercept method thus calls `setNeedsDisplay:` on a background thread.

Have all UI related stuff perform on the main thread. Your best bet is to use Grand Central Dispatch, unless you need to support iOS < 4 or OS X < 10.6 (or was it 10.7?), like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // perform UI updates
});
```

Comment: Sounds promising! I will give this a shot :)